# Theoretically, can time be controlled locally?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, science-fiction, time, time-manipulation

I mean can time be controlled within an area or even a small portion of space?

I would like to mention time-bombs, which either reverse time in a radius of explosion or take time forward. Also nanobots which can control time within tiny areas.

Time span can be controlled.

Is this theoretically possible from what we know about time or is it only fiction?

I have an interesting theory that time can really be controlled locally. There of course is a blended edge at which locally controlled time is blended with current time. However, locally controlled time works differently for objects that were or will be there before or after the current time for the span set and objects that weren't there in the past or won't be there in the future throughout the time span set.

I mean if you reverse time for a zone or take it forward, the slip-through objects were there or will be there for only a certain amount of time (they simply slip-through this area on their way) and thus can't exist there for more or less than that very time. However objects which were there all the time can be reversed to a point back in time, but objects which are taken forward much depend on what could happen in the future to this object, thus it can either stay in that area and we'll see its future in the current time, or it will disappear in the time zone. But since local time is ahead and global time is behind, we won't have this object anywhere anymore, because in our time outside the time zone it doesn't yet exist, but within the time zone at that future time it doesn't already exist.

The human idea is the same.

Imaging you (you-1) are walking with a reversing time bomb in your hand and stop suddenly because you see yourself (you-2) appearing out of nowhere. You-2 starts talking to you and you-1 answer, this goes on for some time until you find yourself (you-1) walking forward while you-2 starts slowly disappearing and then you come to the spot where you-2 was, turn around and throw the reversing time bomb at the spot you were several minutes before. At this moment you become you-2, but in fact you are you-1, whereas you holding a time bomb appears in the local time becomes you-1, while in fact he is you-2. Current you-1 cannot intersect with you-2 outside of what had been done before, you-1 do exactly the same movements the previous you-2 did and say the same words.

Comment: I vote to move this question to physics.se

Comment: @Asqiir It's fine here, no need to move it just because it might be on topic elsewhere

Comment: can a really good kiss count as a time slow?

Comment: Does time have to slow? can objects inside the local space speed up?

Comment: @Reed notice I didn't mention slowing down time, I asked if time could be reversed or taken forward.

Comment: For what you're thinking of, no.

Comment: @Asqiir btw if you close the name of the site in square brackets, ie `[physics.se]` it creates a magic link: [physics.se]

Comment: Does the time need to be "translated" for matter, or is simply affecting the *perception* of those present enough?

Comment: Time manipulation in a certain area is difficult because you usually don't have a fully contained environment. Molecules will want to move into and out of the area which you are trying to reverse so the biggest problem is what happens to that? How can you reverse a breeze if you aren't manipulating all the molecules in the breeze? Does one end form a perfect vacuum and the other end an explosion from a sudden influx of molecules?  What happens if you reverse half a person? Do they get cut in half?

Comment: @Shadowzee Of my theory works then the person we'll see a glimpse of how his half disappeares on the local time and his other half continuous to live in present. Then his disappeared half starts to appear where it should be in the current time as the local time starts to close.

Comment: @SovereignSun there's absolutely nothing in physics suggesting your "theory" has even a grain of truth.  Things cannot cease to exist because they're displaced in time - their mass cannot vanish.  Even if time could be locally controlled/reversed without enormous collateral damage (it cannot), boundary effects would destroy things intersecting them.

Comment: @SovereignSun So I'm assume local time is the time being reversed. Would that mean that anything inside the area will be fully reversed to where they were before, but anything that crossed the border will have to be resolved with the real world once the time manipulation stops? hence avoiding any conflicts between the reversed timeline and actual timeline?

Comment: Draw a diagram, y-axis is time at point A, x-axis is observed position along a line from A to B (observed from A). A ball rolling from A to B will B represented by a line from left to right, going upward. B to A is a line going downward, a ball sitting still is an upright line. Now imagine a time bomb is detonated halfway along the timeline, affecting neither A nor B. What happens to the perceived positions? Timeline is A-specific, so unaffected by the time bomb. This ignores two of the three spatial dimensions, and might be doable. Please post the results.

Comment: @Shadowzee Yes, that's exactly my point, an object that didn't exist in the time zone throughout the reversal cannot be reversed, but it was not always there it has a future marker in a different place, but an object that has a future marker in the very same spot can coexist as past within the now or the future.

Comment: @bukwyrm This needs to be done, surely, but isn't it exactly what I have given in words?

Comment: Not exactly, no. I did not even get the impression that you thought you knew what should happen, which is why i recommended this exercise.

Answer (score 39):

In modern physics, the only thing which is capable of altering the flow of time with respect to two points in space is gravity.  In general relativity, the passage of time and gravity are inherently entwined, so "time travels slower" near massive objects.  If you have a very massive object (as in black-hole massive), you can noticeably distort time.  Of course, given that you've got enough mass/gravity to distort time, you also make a [mess of things](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghettification) in space as well.  If you've got enough mass to slow things down meaningfully, you most likely also have enough mass to simply rip matter into teeny-weenie bits, which probably makes a bigger impact than the time slowing.

Other than that, time manipulation effects are 100% science fiction.  Even stuff that's quite far from what I would call "nanobots controlling time" like wormholes back in time are still considered to be science fiction as they require that our current theories work perfectly in extreme situations *and* call for exotic forms of matter that we literally don't even see whispers of.

At the very least, if you are inventing such a science fiction device, pay attention to whether or not it could be used to create a perpetual motion machine or infinite energy.  It's *really really* easy to accidentally make a pseudo-physics which permits time manipulation that also lets you do cheap tricks (like gathering the energy from a nuclear bomb, then using time travel magic to rewind time for that bomb and set it off again).  You either want to come up with a rationale why your approach cannot create infinite energy, or create a world where your physics won't break down in the presence of such infinite energies.

Comment: My God, I actually don't understand most of it. Especially the second part about infinite energy.

Comment: @SovereignSun The most common problem of time travel in science fiction is that you could repeat an event that releases alot of enery and harness it, and thus break the law of conservation of energy. You would basically create free energy, and the universe has something against that...

Comment: @DarthDonut That, of course, assumes there is almost no energy cost associated with the time travel compared to the energy event being harnessed. It is extremely doubtful any form of time travel will be energy cheap. Also, time machines can be expected to break before they can generate infinite energy.

Comment: _"time travels slower" near massive objects_... from the perspective of a different observer. Time passes normally for you _and the observer_, regardless of acceleration or the gravity that's experienced, but they'd disagree on what the other would have been through. That's assuming you're not making a blackhole, in which case nobody would know anything about anyone.

Comment: +1 for the issue of infinite energy and other shenanigans. This is not specific to time travel, as it applies to any scientific discovery or magical ability, but it can completely wreak the suspension of disbelief of the readers when one realizes that there's a way to create infinite energy/matter...

Comment: @MatthieuM. : True, even just a simple portal system can do it, by placing two portal upon each other horizontally, letting a magnetic object to fall infinitely, and putting coils around it.

Comment: @a4android, actually it simply means that if you took fuel A used it up to travel back in time and then used that same fuel from further back before it was already used you could create an infinite looping event thus creating infinite energy. the main issue there is that's its paradoxical and tends to break everything worse than dividing by 0

Comment: @BladeWraith Paradoxes like that only tell you the physical model is wrong. Physicists have a mantra" "Infinities mean there's new physics ahead." Any time travel where you use the same fuel earlier will prevent the first time travel from happening. I've published enough articles on time travel not to believe in infinite loops.

Comment: For your last point, just treat the device as a black box. It's soft sci-fi territory anyways, might as well embrace it. The device does the one thing. How it does it is either unknown because it's far more advanced than our knowledge of science or way above your clearance level. *It just works*. All you need is do something incredibly cool with it to distract people from asking annoying questions.

Comment: I wouldn't want it to be pure fiction. I prefer a grain of science in it.

Comment: @DarthDonut I've heard one possible resolution to the time travel paradox is the idea that a parallel universe is spawned everytime time travel takes place. That is, if I went back in time and killed Hitler, I'd actually have traveled back to "Earth II" and killed "Hitler II". Life on "Earth I" goes on like normal, so no paradox takes place. If OP decided to adopt that idea, does that keep the conservation of energy from being broken? You're never "reusing" the same energy, just a different universe's energy from a parallel event. Still handwavey, but does that solve the infinite energy issue?

Comment: @LordFarquaad That is the multiverse resolution to the paradox.  And you are correct that it sidesteps many infinite energy paradoxes.  Another neat one is the [Novikov self-consistency principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Novikov_self-consistency_principle) which says that physics *should* be self-consistent globally in the presence of time travel.  SoverignSun, the billiard ball experiments mentioned on the wikipedia article are probably the most elegant way to approach the principle and are relatively easy to understand.

Comment: @LordFarquaad AFAIK, that works, but you have to consider what happens to the physical matter of whatever is being sent back in time. Matter and energy can't be destroyed, meaning that in Earth 1 the stuff you still transported back in time would still have to be there. Matter also can't be created, so where does the stuff come from in Earth 2?

Comment: I don't follow your infinite-energy-harvesting example. Say I don't harvest energy but 'only' mass: I can go back in time and steal some object, but I cannot go back in time and steal the same object once more ending up with twice the same object. Of course, that's the basic paradox of time travel: If I went back in time and removed an object, will the object still be there for me to take if I go back to some other (later) point in time? Can I go back and take my grandparents from their time before my parents are born and still expect my parents to be born in the original time line?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about energy/mass conservation across time travel. Hardly anyone does in fiction. Per our current understanding, time travel is as impossible as creating/destroying energy or mass, so time travel may well not be subject to much of the other laws of physics we normally observe. Heck, the common time travel always implicitly exchanges *volume*; only recently I saw a film where for the first time there was a shockwave both in the place of departure ('implosion') and the destination ('explosion') when people instantly 'disappeared' or 'appeared' respectively.

Comment: @JimmyB that's possibly breaking the speeds of sound and light combined that cause the explosion, since the people probably didn't just teleport but moved at a speed a million times faster than lightspeed.

Answer (score 3):

Under currently understood physics, time cannot be sped up or reversed in any way.  However, time can be slowed down with the use of gravitational wells or extreme speed (which essentially equate to the same thing at some point).  This leads to the possibility of using small black holes to slow down time in specific areas to mimic some of the effects you were listing.  Theoretically, these black holes could be controlled through electromagnetic fields if they were highly charged enough (see: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/64379/do-black-holes-have-charges).

However, in no case could this reverse time.  Additionally, I  think nanobots would be impractical given that they would have to carry around black holes at insane speeds.  However, speeding up time could be mimicked by slowing down time for everything around whatever you want to speed up.  This could lead to some interesting scenarios if you could weaponize a black hole that's made entirely out of electrons or something.

Comment: There is one way to speed up time: just be in a reference frame in which time is slowed down from the other guy's perspective.

Answer (score 3):

Any way I try to handwave this, it goes wrong or very wrong. From less to more nasty (or from more fiction to less fiction):

- It works, it causes the particles inside to evolve backwards in time. Pretty much nothing special happens, as most phenomena has time symetry. Perhaps a few dedicated experiments can figure out something is going on.
- We just say it works like a tape recorder. We throw an object, and the detonate the time bomb in the path of the obejct. The object is on the other side, beyond the radius of the bomb... but time inside is reverted... will a second object sudently appear? This can create time duplicates. We could get free energy.
- There is idea in science that antiparticles are particles traveling back in time. If this is true, and the bomb reverses time... Everything inside is antimater for the outside, and everything outside is antimater for the inside. Anihilation ensues, huge nuclear explosion.
- Let's say we break the principle of universality to allow different laws of physics to work on different places of the universe: Everyway the arrow of time goes one way, but in a bubble it goes the other. Now you have an edge, that will split apart atoms and whatnot, we have runaway fission, a nuclear fire ball.
- Let us say, we change it smoothly. Time goes normally outside, but in the inside time goes backwards, this means that there must be an event horizon at which time is stoped. We have created a gravitational well, so strong that it can stop time, for all uses and purposes we created a black hole.
- Let us say, we use wormholes instead. We need to bring the past to the future. However, traversable wormholes works both ways. If we want a single way wormhole, we are talking about a whitehole-blackhole pair... with a blackhole in the past and whitehole in the future. Even if things couls survive the fall in the blackhole, the whitehole would push them out in all directions (they explode).

And all that without saying that we need infinite energy to make it work.

I must conclude that for this to work in your world, you will have to consider a universe different from ours.

I only have a couple of solutions:

- This is a universe where there is real and imaginary time, and there is some phenomenon that allows to rotate time, allowing to change the flow of real time (making some or all of it imaginary, or even reverting real time) without the need of gravity.
- The universe is a simulation, and it has been programmed to allow such thing.

Comment: You have a very interesting thought there. I was thinking about it a lot. Earned myself a headache the previous night in fact. If we throw an object and then blow up a time bomb in an area the object earlier passed then as time goes in reverse in that area, the real object must start disappearing and the very same object should start appearing first at the edge of the time-reversed zone and then start moving backwards in the direction it was thrown from, when it exits the time zone it simply disappears withing the time zone and starts reappearing later in time after it had been thrown before,

Comment: The real time for this object shouldn't change if it initially was outside the time-reversed zone. The object wasn't there at the time time went in reverse so we only allow time to show us the object in the past, itself and its state, movement, etc.

Comment: However, if we time-reverse an object which was in the time zone all of the time from now to years in reverse then we do reverse the object, because the object is already there at the time reversed from current time.

Comment: The same goes for taking time forward.

Comment: @SovereignSun If bomb reverts time of all the particles that passed the area, given that they were there but no longer, it would look as if the bomb attracts them, which is why I started thinking of it in terms of gravity. If the bomb does not affect objects outside its radius, then we could get time duplicates, that if you can extract, will allow for free energy, as I mention in the answer... Are they the past of another object, and we have paradox? - on that thought, see the [no-cloning theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-cloning_theorem), the duplicates would diverge at quantum level.

Comment: we don't have duplicates, everything that had passed through the time-zone or wasn't in it before will have to be controlled by both the local time and the global time. If you throw a ball to the ground and then blow a reversing time bomb there then the ball will have to go in reverse. It will first start going up and in the direction it earlier came from and then will disappear from local time zone and appear in global time as if it were in the past but as the object exist it must be physical so you can touch it and hold it even, although it will be moving on itself.

Comment: But when the local time collapses the object should return to its presumably future position and state from earlier present time position and state.

Comment: The thing that bothers me is can you interfere with the past present object as a present object without affecting neither the present, nor the past or future.

Comment: "The universe is a simulation, and it has been programmed to allow such thing."

The only time I've seen this kind of thing done well didn't involve the universe being a simulation, but all time manipulation-like effects were simulated. Of course, this requires your setting to now include some mechanic of simulating the universe _but also hiding that fact_ so people think it's time manipulation, as well as the technology required to create whatever objects or energy are required to make the simulation believable.

Comment: @SovereignSun being able to touch the object, imply you can exchange virtual photons with it. If interactions happens, time passes. Similarly, if you can see it (photons can bounce off it). Also, photons would transfer heat, and that heat is motion. From another perspective, to touch it, you are applying a force to it, transfering energy to it, if it does not move, it is absorbing it. From yet another perspective... not moving respect to what frame of reference? it would be moving in some for it not to be in others.

Comment: @SovereignSun I really don't see a problem with interacting with the past version, if you do not have a problem with it jumping in time (for example, you seem to think the effect of the time bomb start and end at fixed points in time). That changes propagate in time is a trope (*oh, look! the photo changed*), it does not have to work like that. For example, if the past is changed, would people even be able to remember it was was changed? Why would they. If you change the past, nobody should be aware of it, not even the time traveler.

Comment: @SovereignSun Addendum: by "the effect of the time bomb start and end at fixed points in time", I mean they start and end for the whole volume simultaneously, and whatever was there goes back to be as if the event didn't happen. If you do not want to break universality: 1) It cannot affect the whole volume simultanously - there is no such thing - instead the volume should expand and collapse, at most at the speed of light. 2) When reverse effect ends, it should not go back to the future version. Either, it stays in the old version, or rushes to the present. No jump.

Comment: @Theraot but as time goes in reverse withing that area it goes on globally. Time-manipulation shouldn't break the current timeline, and the current timeline knows where those slip-through objects should be after the stolen time. I think I'll name this effect as "stolen time" in fact. But you can interact with this stolen time and objects within it.

Comment: @SovereignSun as I was saying I don't see a problem with interacting with it. However, if you can interact with it, you can change it. You need to decide what happens then. You can go with the tropes, or you can do something else. This is the first time you mention time lines, I can't claim to know how your universe resolves that parts... yet, as I was saying, that changes propagate is a trope, you can do something else.

Comment: @SovereignSun As for the time line knowing where the particles will be, I would be against that. Particles do not have identity, we cannot know their position and momentum at the same time, a record of the quantum state of an object at a given time is not possible (see no-cloning theorem, I linked earlier), and the particles that make up and object are always changing. With that said, you choose to break that, it is worldbuilding after all. You can have sentient time lines if you want to. Suggestion: pick pilot wave theory over classic quantum theory.

Answer (score 0):

if we accept that time is global to the universe, with local distortions in deep gravity wells, then no, you cannot have local effects.

IF you also postulate alternate universes and that they can be created, manipulated, and destroyed on the fly then you could:

1. wrap a part of our universe in a pocket universe
2. change the rate of time flow in the pocket
3. open the pocket to restore the part removed

that would have the effect of localized time alterations .. with a whole lot of hand waving at the physicists that are writhing in pain as they read this hokum. Enjoy.